# I want the filter to have two options

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I wonder how I can add another filter to my script? Because now it is filtering only the country, and I want to filter something else along with that :

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.filters a', function() {

      var filter = $(this).attr('data-country');

      if ( filter == 'all' ) {
         $('.items a').show();
      } else {
         $('.items a').hide();
         $('.items a[data-country="' + filter + '"]').show();
      }

      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: `$('.items a[data-country="us"][data-age="13"]')` something like that

Comment: yes, something like that, but - what  do I have to write before this line? This script was given to me. I am not that good at Jquery

Comment: That part isn't even about jQuery; that's just normal JavaScript String manipulation...